# When viewing a profile, search should default to searching that account on teams

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

On Public Q&A - I often go to a profile as an easy way to search for posts by that account. It will pre-populate the user ID in the search bar

[image: Screenshot of MSO showing search bar with userid:674571]

On SO for teams it does not - which can be rather inconvenient

[image: Screenshot of SO for teams - with the team name blurred out and showing no userid in search bar]

Could we harmonise how SO for teams behaves with public Q&A?